# System boots directly in to Windows without showing boot-loader option

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 14.10, bootloader

I have installed  Windows 8.1 as dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.xx . dual boot of my system is working fine.... but last night boot-loader is not appearing and the system boots directly in to Windows,My BIOS is set to UEFI?

Comment: Were you booting from `Grub` or Windows boot-loader before this?

Comment: window boot-loader

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the windows boot loader use

```
bcdedit /timeout 15
```

If you are using grub use the `Shift` key, to get the menu.